# SQL filter for parent child tree structure

Tags: sql, filter, tree

So I have a database where each record has a reference to a parent record in the same table (possibly null). Each record also has an 'active' flag that describes whether the single record is currently active.

I would like to end up with a flat list of records that have the following traits:

- Is active
- Contains no inactive ancestors

Instead of constructing the tree and doing a search to filter out the records I would like to accomplish this in SQL. Is there a way to join or aggregate to filter out the undesired records?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using CTEs and recursive querying (if your database system supports it).

There is a SQL Server example [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx) and a Postgres example [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-with.html).